# upper bound failing in binary search

Tags: c

I am implementing binary search iteratively, and I am searching find data in my array.

```html
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[10] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
    int find = 12;
    int size = 10;
    int pos = 0;
    int mid;
    while(pos<=size)
    {
        mid = pos+(size-pos)/2;
        printf("mid = %d %d\n",mid,arr[mid]);

        if(arr[mid] == find){
            printf("mid = %d %d\n",mid,arr[mid]);
            return printf("position is %d\n",mid+1);
        }
        if(arr[mid]< find)
            pos = mid+1;
        else
            size = mid-1;
    }
    printf("data not found\n");

    return 0;
}
```

But my code is failing when I am trying to find any data above max value given in arr.
I am using codeblocks to compile and run my code.

Comment: this code is working fine when using int find <= 11

Comment: I don't see `12` in `arr`. How do you expect to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Array starts with index 0 and when you iterate you iterate till n-1 element. Your loop:

```
while(pos<=size)
```

Should be changed to

```
while(pos<size)
```

So it doesn't move beyond the elements that you haven't defined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the array bound are not specified properly while searching.Array starts with index 0.Thus in your case arr[10] means array elements starts at arr[0] and last element is arr[9].Thus the size variable should be set to n-1 i.e. 10-1 = 9.
Thus the code should be

```
int size = 9;
```

or alternatively, instead of changing size you can change while loop as

```
while(pos<size)
```